# Getting a specific field in a document returned from firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So, I have a problem that can probably be super easily solved I just can't quite figure it out. 
Essentially at this point, I'm trying to store fields of a specific document into 2 vars so that I can use them elsewhere.

This is my firestore hierarchy:

[image]

This is the code I have so far and I think I'm on the right track but I don't know what to replace "//What do I put here" with.

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var usersEmail = user.email;
db.collection("users").where("email", "==", usersEmail)
                    .get()
                    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                            var firstName = //What do I put here?
                            var lastName = //What do I put here?
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
                    });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`doc.data()` is just a regular JavaScript object with the contents of the document you just read:

```
var data = doc.data();
var firstName = data.first;
var lastName = data.last;
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thanks!

Comment: Why in sometimes is need use doc.data and in others is need doc.data() ? with " () ", what is difference between use or not use.

Comment: What if you only want to grab a specific field of that document instead of reading the whole document? Would that save any resources at all?

Comment: @小红书 as far as I know, Firebase is billing for every document, not for every field we get, so I think it gets the whole document in the snapshot, but you just get the field if you don't want to store the whole document in your application.

Answer (score 6):

Or you can get the field value directly from the `DocumentSnapshot`:

```
var firstName = doc.get("first");
var lastName = doc.get("last");
```