# Remove Firebase Wrapper (Proxy / Target) (Quasar)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, quasar-framework

I am retrieving a document from Firebase and putting it into an array in Quasar.

When I do this, I cannot console.log out the individual parts of the array. I need to have the Firebase Document ID as part of my array, that's why I'm doing it like this. I couldn't find a better way to do that other than using the snapshot.

Also, I'm looping through all the documents retrieved from Firebase to find the one I want. I wasn't able to figure out how to do a query(collection... and select only the document ID I want.  Anyway... that works, but I can't access any of the elements inside the array.

```
        const q = query(collection(db, "eventTable"))
    
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            let listChange = change.doc.data()
            listChange.id = change.doc.id
            if (listChange.id == this.fbEventID) {
                this.theEvent.unshift(listChange) 
            }
            // this makes sure the ID is included in the array.
          }) // end snapshot.docChanges()
        }) // end const unsubscribe = onSnapShot

       console.log(' this.theEvent: ', this.theEvent) // this works
       console.log(' this.theEvent: ', this.theEvent.fb_email) // this does not work
       console.log(' this.theEvent: ', this.theEvent[0]) // this does not work
       console.log(' this.theEvent: ', this.theEvent[0].fb_email) // this does not work
```

This is what my array object looks like. I don't know what the Proxy and Target areas are, and would like to know.

[image]

This is what it looks like when I expand [0]:
Part 1:
[image]

Part 2:
[image]

I'm assuming that Firebase putting a wrapper around it that's not letting me access the individual elements in the array.  How do I unwrap it so I can console.log out (and do other things with) the individual elements?

If I am incorrect and it's not a Firebase wrapper, I'm open to that too. :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code snippet, I believe you are using the Firebase V9 modular JS SDK to do this. In that case, based on this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68441774/), you can perform queries for specific document IDs by importing and using the `documentID()` function:

```
const q = query(collection(firestoreDB, "users"), where(documentId(), "==", "testUser1")); //My doc ID is “testUser1”
```

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query) is more information on what types of queries you can perform. I tested this, based also from this [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52462129/) and it might solve the issue of not being able to query specific properties from documents stored in your array, as doing something like `docArr[0].firstName` worked, here is my test code:

```
import { app } from "./firestore-config";
import { getFirestore, getDocs, collection, query, where, documentId } from "firebase/firestore";

export default function App() {
  const firestoreDB = getFirestore(app);
  const q = query(collection(firestoreDB, "users"), where(documentId(), "==", "testUser1"));
  let docArr = [];

  const getData = async () => {
    const qSnap = await getDocs(q);
    qSnap.forEach((doc) => {
      docArr.push(doc.data());
    });
  }

  getData().then(() => {
    console.log(docArr[0].firstName); //Makes sure to query the array after fetching the documents
  });
}
```

Testing this in the browser dev console only outputs the `firstName` property of my document:

[image]